# Parse wrapped typed array with Axios

Tags: javascript, typescript, api, axios

I am using TypeScript and Axios. I have the following classes:

```
class Item {
  private a: string = '';
  private b: string = '';

  public constructor(options: any = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}

class Items {
  private items: Array<Item> = [];

  public constructor(options: any = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }

  public getItems(): Array<Item> {
    return this.items;
  }
}
```

My backend responses are similar to:

```
{
  "items": [
    {"a": "a1", "b": "b1", "c": "c1"},
    {"a": "a2", "b": "b2", "c": "c2"}
  ]
}
```

As a result I want to get an `Items` class that contains all `Item`s with the fields `a` and `b` (`c` should be ignored).

I tried the following:

```
Axios.get<Items>('path-to-backend-api').then((response) => {
  const items: Items = (new Items(response.data));
});
```

However, the resulting `items` object's inner array is empty. I also wanted to invoke JS's `map` on the `response.data.items` array, but couldn't get the type system to work. `const items: response.data.getItems()` failed as well. I tried about a dozen other less typed approaches, but couldn't find a solution.

How could I construct a `Array<Item` object based on the above JSON response?

Comment: Did you try deserialize json to your model ?

Comment: First narrow down the problem. 1. log response.data. Dou you receive anything? In the desired format (like camel case vs snake case)? 2. Generic type for axios.get is only a hint for the compiler, it is not enforced in any way. Thus, you will never receive an instance of a class (the prototype chain will not be established). Avoid this pitfall by using an interface or a type, not a class to specify the received data type. Map to class manually if needed.

Comment: 1. Yes, I logged the `resopnse.data` and it was what was expected.
2. I am pretty unfamiliar with TypeScript/Axios, so if you think there's a solution based on interfaces, you could paste it as an answer. I don't mind changing my code a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, multiple things to unpack here.

**The generic type passed to [`Axios.get<T>()`](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L140) should represent the shape of incoming deserialised data i.e. `response.data`.** You are passing `Items` which is a `class` you are creating a new instance of using the incoming data. They are separate and should be declared separately.

Whilst you **can** use a [`class` as an interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#using-a-class-as-an-interface), it doesn't really suit your implementation to do so.

`response.data.getItems()` is impossible with your current implementation. If you really want to be able to do this (you probably don't), you could add a `transformResponse` function to your [Axios request config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config) that creates a new `class` instance from the data before delivering it in the `response` of `Axios.get()`.

With minimal changes to your original code, here's what I'd suggest doing to type correctly and make your code more flexible:

```js
interface ItemData {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}

interface ItemsData {
  items: ItemData[];
}

class Item implements ItemData {
  a: string = '';
  b: string = '';

  constructor(options: ItemData) {
    Object.assign(this, options);
  }
}

class Items {
  items: Item[] = [];

  constructor(options: ItemsData) {
    Object.assign(this.items, options.items.map(item => new Item(item));
  }

  getItems(): Item[] {
    return this.items;
  }
}

Axios.get<ItemsData>('path-to-backend-api').then((response) => {
  const items: Items = new Items(response.data);

  // now you can use the class methods
  const list = items.getItems();
});
```